# Strong Atiyah conjecture

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, gr.group-theory

Who introduced the Strong Atiyah Conjecture?

Recall that the conjecture says the following. Let $G$ be a group, $A$ a $n\times n$-matrix over ${\mathbb Z}G$. We view $A$ as a bounded operator $l^2(G)^n\to l^2(G)^n$. Let $K$ be the kernel of that operator and $p$ be the orthogonal projection onto $K$. Let $\delta$ be the function of $l^2(G)$ which is 1 on $1\in G$, and 0 everywere else. Let $e_i$ be the vector from $l^2(G)^n$ with $i$-th coordinate $\delta$, all other coordinates $0$, and $t_A$ be the sum of dot products $\sum_i \langle p(e_i), e_i\rangle$. The conjecture says that $t_A$ always belongs to $\frac1g\mathbb{Z}$ where $g$ is the least common multiple of the orders of finite subgroups of $G$ (so if $G$ is torsion-free, $t_A$ must be an integer).

Comment: Certainly not Atiyah. 

Comment: @Ben: Of course not. 

Comment: My conjecture is that it was Linnell or Schick.

Comment: I am pretty sure I heard a talk by Grigorchuk 10 years ago where he said who made the strong conjecture but I can't remember anymore the attribution. 

Comment: There is also the "super-strong Atiyah conjecture": the one which states that $t_A\in \frac1{g'}{\mathbb Z}$ where $g'$ is the least common multiple of orders of elements of $G$. That conjecture has been solved in negative by many people including Grigorchuk. I think that the "strong Atiyah" is still open.  

Comment: All Atiyah conjectured are now disproved I believe. Examples have been given of irrational L2 betti numbers. In fact it has been shown the possible L2 Betti numbers form an uncountable set. 

Comment: Grigorchuk got a 1/3 for the Z2 lamplighter. 

Comment: @Ben: Only the super-strong conjecture has been disproved (by several people). Grigorchuk's paper was co-authored by Linnell, Schick and Zuk. There are now examples of groups and matrices $A$ with transcendental $t_A$, etc. The lamplighter group contains finite subgroups of arbitrary large sizes, so it does not disprove the strong conjecture which is still open. There are some positive results by Linnell, Okun, Schick and others. The original Atiyah's conjecture (which is the strong conjecture but only for one particular $1\times 1$-matrix $A$) is wide open.  

Comment: What does (1/g)Z mean if there is no bound on the least common multiple of all finite subgroups?  You must have in mind some meaning which allows the transcendental L2 betti numbers that people have constructed.  All of these examples I do believe have unbounded subgroups of finite order. 

Comment: If there is no bound, $g$ is not defined, and the conjecture does not make sense. It only makes sense when $g\lt \infty$. 

Comment: During the rigidity semester at the Hausdorff Institute at Bonn, in dec. 2009, Austin lectured about his results from http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.2360.pdf
and someone gossiped: now that the conjecture is disproved, Atiyah insists that it should be called L\"uck's conjecture. For what it's worth...

Comment: @Alain: Wolfgang Lueck says it was probably introduced by Schick (I asked yesterday). I suspect that Linnell was earlier. I will ask Schick, just to make sure. 

Comment: Also only the superstrong conjecture has been disproved. So the strong one can still be called Atiyah. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I received a message from Thomas Schick, which answers my question. The strong 
Atiyah conjecture was introduced jointly by Lueck and Schick (this was also one of the alternatives in Wolfgang Lueck's email to me), and Thomas Schick is responsible for the super-strong one. He was a postdoc working with Wolfgang Lueck at that time.  Peter Linnell came to the $l_2$-Betti theory via Kaplansky's zero divisors conjecture (these are related) and learned about various forms of Atiyah conjectures from Wolfgang Lueck. In any case, the various forms of Atiyah's conjecture have generated a lot of interesting mathematics already and probably will generate more.

If there are no other answers, I will then accept this one.